# How does ElasticBeanstalk create an IIS .NET application?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Coming from a background where I've always used the 'Import Application' functionality in IIS, I'm a little lost in terms of how AWS handles this.

Looking at the deployment logs, I can see Beanstalk copies the bin folder into the root Default Website with all the DLLs, there's also the webconfigs there too.

But even when logging onto the instance, I can't hit my application at all, all requests return 404 (even */status* which is a basic Nancy module I've set up).

```
http://localhost/status
```

What I'm struggling to answer is:

- Was the application actually 'created' in IIS, or did it just copy the files into the root directory?
- The Default Website is running, but is the application running?
- Does 'Import Application' do something more than just copy the files over?

My code works 100% when deployed the 'Import Application' way.